# "Watch Sass" not showing in status bar in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Watch Sass option is not showing up in the status bar after installing the Live Sass Compiler extension in Visual Studio Code. It is the updated one by Glenn Marks.
[image]

Here's the step I took, but I haven't figured out the solution yet:

I right-clicked the status bar to check if it was enabled, and it was enabled.
[image]

In addition, I pressed F1 and selected **watch Sass** and it compiled the SCSS. See the photo:
[image]

But, it doesn't resolve my problem, which is to have a **Watch Sass button** in the status bar, just like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ehmmm, I think your status bar is not really visible, I had the same issue, just fixed mine.

Click on customize layout icon, hover on the status bar and activate the visible icon.